# "You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping. Make sure they are balanced" when adding two canvases

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

I'm getting this error in my unity project. It only occurs when I add an empty image to my newly created second canvas. I need two canvases because the first one is used in world view as a health bar floating above my player, the second one is used for the GUI XP bar. The "empty image" is for the purpose of creating an XP bar slider. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This sounds like a unity bug to me, maybe try opening a bug report

Comment: This usually happens in faulty Inspector scripts .. do you have any custom ones in your project?